# bash ffmpeg command not found

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, centos7

I have a CentOS machine on which I want to install ffmpeg. I tried

```
yum install ffmpeg
```

but unable to install and showing errors on the console

```
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libtheoradec.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libSDL-1.2.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libSDL-1.2.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libv4l2.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.28()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libass.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libopenjpeg.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgsm.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libcdio_paranoia.so.1(CDIO_PARANOIA_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libpulse.so.0(PULSE_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libva.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_3_0_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libschroedinger-1.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libtheoraenc.so.1(libtheoraenc_1.0)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

then I followed this [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) this created a bin folder having

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 21545536 Dec 14 19:38 ffmpeg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 21452512 Dec 14 19:38 ffprobe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 19227136 Dec 14 19:38 ffserver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   505728 Dec 14 19:11 lame
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2779368 Dec 14 18:51 nasm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1078048 Dec 14 18:51 ndisasm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2550848 Dec 14 18:54 vsyasm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2548168 Dec 14 18:54 yasm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2526096 Dec 14 18:54 ytasm
```

and when I try to run

```
[root@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX bin]# ffmpeg
```

it shows

```
bash: ffmpeg: command not found
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Use `./ffmpeg` instead, `ffmpeg` searches for the command in `$PATH` but since your current directory `/root/bin` is not in `$PATH`, it cannot find the command

Comment: Off-topic, this has nothing to do with programming, but with "how to use centos".

Comment: could be off topic.. can you answer this?

Comment: Looks like your packaging system is either broken or out of date, maybe try `yum clean all` first and reinstall...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy or move the `ffmpeg` file into `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: still the same issue. even there is ffmpeg file, why i cant run?

Comment: Show output of `echo $PATH`.

Comment: i have user2 from which this is working.. but i want that it shoul work for all the users

Comment: @SunilGarg It should work for all users. Hard to say why it doesn't work for a particular user without more info.

Answer (score 1):

This is a repo issue. Just update your repo files, then do `yum clean all` and at last `yum install -y ffmpeg` will load requirements and dependencies.

Comment: and how can I do that? Actually, i am the windows user, not much knowledge about that?

Comment: your repo files are stored in /etc/yum.repos.d  you can either edit them or add a new one (you can just download a good one from centos or from another centos user or copy/paste from any good sources for example http://vault.centos.org/4.2/CentOS-Base.repo )